# multiple colons in css

Tags: css

I have seen a line of code in CSS looks like this:

```
[icon]:not([focused]):not([pressed]):not([disabled]){ background-position-y:-0px;  }
```

What is the meaning of the multiple colons in this case? Are they still Pseudo selectors?

Comment: @j08691, technically it is regular CSS except for `background-position-y`, which is nonstandard (proposed and implemented in some browsers, but not in any spec or draft). While e.g. `icon` is not a valid HTML attribute, CSS is not limited to styling valid HTML.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's not pseudo-selectors - it's selectors for pseudo-classes. Quoting the [W3C Selectors Level 3 doc](http://www.w3.org/TR/2011/REC-css3-selectors-20110929/#negation):

> **6.6.7. The negation pseudo-class**
>   The negation pseudo-class, `:not(X)`, is a functional notation taking a simple selector (excluding the negation pseudo-class itself) as an argument. It represents an element that is not represented by its argument. [...]
>
> The following selector matches all button elements in an HTML document
>   that are not disabled.
>
> `button:not([DISABLED])`
>
> The following group of selectors represents all HTML elements except links.
>
> `html|*:not(:link):not(:visited)`

The last example (as well as [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5684160/multiple-not-selector)) shows that it's quite valid to use a chain of several `:not` pseudo-class selectors, if what you want is setting a rule for some element that is not either of *several* mentioned types.

In your case the selector catches all the elements with `icon` attribute set (to any value) - except those that have either `focused`, `pressed` or `disabled` set (again, to any value) as well.