# different style for li between first and end

Tags: css

I want to style an ul, but the first li and last li should have different styles than the ones between them.

I know the below code is probably very wrong, but can you see what i'm trying to do?

```
.menu li:hover:not(.menu li:nth-last-child(1)) { border:red solid 1px; }
```

The HTML is only basic, just want some CSS's styles I can use for any other menus.

```
<ul class="menu">
   <li>All</li><li>Refresh</li><li>Saved</li>
</ul>
```

So, how do I style the middle li's when the user hovers over them? I want to do this to avoid putting a border in the middle of each list item.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### First solution: custom styles for first and last elements

One way is to style every `<li>` element and then customize the first and the last ones. For this, [`:first-child`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/:first-child) and [`:last-child`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:last-child) are your friends.

With HTML such as:

```
<ul class="menu">
    <li>All</li>
    <li>Refresh</li>
    <li>Something else</li>
    <li>Saved</li>
</ul>
```

and the following CSS:

```
.menu li:first-child { font-weight: bold; }
.menu li:last-child { font-style: italic; }
```

You'll obtain:

> - **All**
> - Refresh
> - Something else
> - *Saved*

### Second solution: apply a style to element 2 to *n*-1

If you can't, for a reason, define a common style for all list elements, and customize it for the first and the last ones, you can use the `:not` keyword. `.menu li:not(:first-child)` will exclude the first element, and `.menu li:not(:last-child)`—the last one.

Multiple [`:not` are combined](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5684168/240613) this way:

```
element:not(selector1):not(selector2)
```

which means that your CSS becomes:

```
.menu li:not(:first-child):not(:last-child)
```

For example:

```
.menu li:not(:first-child):not(:last-child) { font-weight: bold; }
```

will produce:

> - All
> - **Refresh**
> - **Something else**
> - Saved

Comment: Baah you beat me to it!

Comment: Been using them, so I can style the first one and end, but how can I style the ones in between without styling the first and end one?

Answer (score 0):

Try using a CSS selector. The code below will affect the first and last child of the parent (UL).

```
ul:first-child {
 Style attributes here
}

ul:last-child {
  Style attributes here
}
```

More info on CSS selectors here http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css_selectors.asp