# :not() selector not behaving the same between Safari and Chrome/Firefox

Tags: css, google-chrome, firefox, safari, css-selectors

I am having a pretty hard time figuring out why the following code renders in blue in Safari but in red in Chrome and Firefox.

```css
em:not(div) {
    color: red
}
em:not(p div) {
    color: blue
}
```

```html
<p>
    <em>FOO</em>
</p>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/hzcLpf9L/

Apparently it looks like Chrome and Firefox do not support `:not()` CSS selectors with multiple levels in them. **(Possible bug?)**

I am very fond of `:not()` selectors and I develop with Safari, therefore when I discovered my website on Chrome I almost had an heart attack. Any explanation on why this strange behavior happens would be highly appreciated.

Comment: It's not a bug, it's just a new feature they haven't implemented yet.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Safari recently shipped the [level 4 version of `:not()`](https://drafts.csswg.org/selectors-4/#negation), which allows complex selectors for arguments, putting it [on par with jQuery's hitherto non-standard implementation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10711730/why-is-my-jquery-not-selector-not-working-in-css). See the [release notes](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/content/releasenotes/General/WhatsNewInSafari/Articles/Safari_9_0.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014305-CH9-SW34). The [current incarnation of `:not()`](https://www.w3.org/TR/css3-selectors/#negation) only allows a single simple selector for an argument, so a complex selector like `p div` will not work in today's browsers by design.

A complex selector is an expression consisting of one or more compound selectors separated by combinators such as descendant, `>`, `~` and `+`. A compound selector is a sequence of one or more simple selectors. `div` is a compound selector consisting of one simple selector, and `p div` is a complex selector consisting of two compound selectors (each of which consists of one simple selector), separated by a descendant combinator.

It is currently not known when this will land in the other browsers, though it's unlikely the new specification of `:not()` will change at this point — the current level 4 definition is a no-brainer and if the original WebKit strain is daring enough to implement it, then it's really only a matter of time before it makes its way into the other strains (including Blink).

After almost five grueling years of waiting since the FPWD, we might actually finally get to see a CR of selectors-4 real soon. Consider me pumped.

Comment: so the following expression swiped from the latest boostrap is broken: `.btn-group > .btn:not(:last-child):not(.dropdown-toggle), .btn-group > .btn-group:not(:last-child) > .btn { ...styles here...
}`

Comment: @Brian Sweeney: Sorry could you clarify? Is it broken in browsers or was it incorrectly written by the Bootstrap authors?

Comment: if I understand your answer, than it is not an expression that should appear in the booststrap css because it will not work for all browsers.  Does that make sense?

Comment: @Brian Sweeney: Those selectors conform to level 3, because each :not() only contains one argument, and is chained together with its respective .btn or .btn-group class selector without combinators, which is a different issue to what's described here.

Answer (score 6):

From [the spec](https://www.w3.org/TR/css3-selectors/#negation):

> The negation pseudo-class, :not(X), is a functional notation taking a **simple selector** (excluding the negation pseudo-class itself) as an argument. It represents an element that is not represented by its argument.

and [elsewhere in the spec](https://www.w3.org/TR/css3-selectors/#simple-selectors-dfn):

> A simple selector is either a type selector, universal selector, attribute selector, class selector, ID selector, or pseudo-class.

---

The behaviour of Chrome and Firefox is correct. A descendant combinator may not appear in a simple selector (and thus, a :not pseudo-class)

---

This may change in Selectors Level 4. The current [editor's draft](https://drafts.csswg.org/selectors-4/#negation) allows more complex selectors. You appear to have encountered an experimental implementation.