# Is it ok to use the CSS3 selector :not()

Tags: css, css-selectors

I have used :not() in several sites presuming as with other css3 selectors that cross-device / browser support would be good.

When looking on caniuse - http://caniuse.com/#search=%3Anot() the table suggests that only safari browsers support this selector

Whereas w3schools say differently - http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/sel_not.asp

Can anyone shine any light om this?  Ive used the selector heavily over the past few years and want to make sure i should continue to do so!

Comment: http://caniuse.com/#feat=css-sel3 you mean this

Comment: It says for the first result: "Selectors Level 4 allows the :not() pseudo-class **to accept a list of selectors**, which the element must not match any of. **Selectors Level 3 only allowed :not() to accept a single simple selector.** Thus, :not(a):not(.b):not([c]) can instead be written as :not(a, .b, [c])"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The one that is safari only says

> Selectors Level 4 allows the `:not()` pseudo-class to accept a list of
>   selectors, which the element must not match any of. Selectors Level 3
>   only allowed `:not()` to accept a single simple selector. Thus,
>   `:not(a):not(.b):not([c])` can instead be written as `:not(a, .b, [c])`

Which means this form `:not(a, .b, [c])` can be used oppose to this form `:not(a):not(.b):not([c])` but only within safari

http://caniuse.com/#feat=css-sel3 tells us

> Advanced element selection using selectors including: `[foo^="bar"]`,
>   `[foo$="bar"]`, [`foo*="bar"]`, `:root`, `:nth-child()`, `:nth-last-child()`,
>   `nth-of-type`, `nth-last-of-type()`, `:last-child`, `:first-of-type`,
>   :`last-of-type`, `:only-child`, `:only-of-type`, `:empty`, `:target`, `:enabled`,
>   `:disabled`, `:checked`, `:not()`, `~` (general sibling)

Which means we can use all of those selectors including `:not()` in any browser, well all major and updated browsers.

hope that clears it up.

Answer (score 3):

Since you did a search, you were presented with 3 results that matched your query. The first result is the [selector list argument of :not()](http://caniuse.com/#feat=css-not-sel-list) which, I presume, is what you were looking at. Obviously, this isn't the [css selector](http://caniuse.com/#feat=css-sel3) that you were looking for.

So yes, you can safely keep using `:not()`. Here's the correct [canIuse link](http://caniuse.com/#feat=css-sel3) for css selectors.

Comment: See also: [:not selector not behaving the same between Safari and Chrome/Firefox](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35993727/not-selector-not-behaving-the-same-between-safari-and-chrome-firefox)

Comment: @BoltClock interesting, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

[click](http://caniuse.com/#feat=css-sel3)

:not() is **okay** to use ! 
You looked at the wrong one