# :not() pseudo class example only works in Safari

Tags: css, pseudo-class

I thought this was a straightforward use of the :not() pseudoclass, but it doesn't seem to work in most browsers, so I made a [codepen](http://codepen.io/dangoodspeed/pen/ORNZxp) about it.

[Demo example](http://codepen.io/dangoodspeed/pen/pEymBA)

```
.YYY:not(.ZZZ .YYY) {}
```

---

**Updated**

Need solution for [the](http://codepen.io/dangoodspeed/pen/ORNZxp) below css rule

```
.YYY:not(.AAA + .YYY) {}
```

Comment: Was the question not answered?

Comment: See: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35993727/not-selector-not-behaving-the-same-between-safari-and-chrome-firefox

Answer (score 2):

Here's what I gather, somebody correct me if I misunderstand something.

**TLDR**: According to the spec, `:not(X)` accepts as argument a *simple selector* which is different from a *sequence of simple selectors*. Thus, it's not even supposed to work, and Safari is just going against the spec.

---

Spec: https://drafts.csswg.org/selectors-3/#negation

> The negation pseudo-class, :not(X), is a functional notation taking a simple selector (excluding the negation pseudo-class itself) as an argument.

Spec: https://drafts.csswg.org/selectors-3/#simple-selectors-dfn

> A simple selector is either a type selector, universal selector, attribute selector, class selector, ID selector, or pseudo-class.
>
> Combinators are: whitespace, "greater-than sign" (U+003E, >), "plus sign" (U+002B, +) and "tilde" (U+007E, ~). White space may appear between a combinator and the simple selectors around it. Only the characters "space" (U+0020), "tab" (U+0009), "line feed" (U+000A), "carriage return" (U+000D), and "form feed" (U+000C) can occur in whitespace. Other space-like characters, such as "em-space" (U+2003) and "ideographic space" (U+3000), are never part of whitespace.
>
> The elements of a document tree that are represented by a selector are the subjects of the selector. A selector consisting of a single sequence of simple selectors represents any element satisfying its requirements. Prepending another sequence of simple selectors and a combinator to a sequence imposes additional matching constraints, so the subjects of a selector are always a subset of the elements represented by the last sequence of simple selectors.

Note the difference between talking about a *simple selector* and a *sequence of simple selectors*.

Spec: https://drafts.csswg.org/selectors-3/#changesFromCSS2

> the list of basic definitions (selector, group of selectors, simple selector, etc.) has been changed; in particular, what was referred to in CSS2 as a simple selector is now called a sequence of simple selectors, and the term "simple selector" is now used for the components of this sequence

Answer (score 1):

Alternatively you can use this css rule which serves the purpose

```
.YYY {
  font-size: 24px;
  text-align: center;
}

 *:not(.ZZZ) > .YYY {
  color:red;
}
```

Here is the [codepen link](http://codepen.io/rajugt/pen/VKaJWY)

Comment: Thanks.  Though I really simplified my specific case for the demo. How would you write this updated pen to get it work with spec?
http://codepen.io/dangoodspeed/pen/ORNZxp

Comment: Ufff! `+` operator in `not() + css_selector` is not working. Only > and ~ are working. This is the max I can help you now [codepen](http://codepen.io/rajugt/pen/ALKZvZ) without + operator. I suggest you to use parent css class as mentioned in the above answer to simplify the problem.

Comment: Damn.  Well, thanks for your help!  Hopefully some future CSS3 spec will work with these selectors as I wrote them.  It's pretty handy.

Answer (score 0):

According to the [CSSWG draft](https://drafts.csswg.org/selectors-3/#negation), the negation pseudo-class accepts a **simple selector** as its parameter.

> A **selector** is a chain of one or more sequences of simple selectors
>   separated by combinators. One pseudo-element may be appended to the
>   last sequence of simple selectors in a selector.
>
> A **sequence of simple selectors** is a chain of simple selectors that are
>   not separated by a combinator. It always begins with a type selector
>   or a universal selector. No other type selector or universal selector
>   is allowed in the sequence.
>
> A **simple selector** is either a type selector, universal selector,
>   attribute selector, class selector, ID selector, or pseudo-class.

`.ZZZ .YYY` is a selector but not a simple selector, so using it as a parameter for the negation pseudo-class is not supported. Some browsers such as Safari may support it nevertheless, but we shouldn't count on it.