# How to select html table cell with specific class, which is not in the table head

Tags: html, css, css-selectors

I have given HTML page and I'm not allowed to change the html code(e.g. extend the html elements with IDs etc.). 
I'm only allowed to change the layout by using the existing element classes, IDs etc. 
The element for which I want to change the text properties has the class .requestStatus and is in a table call, but this is not the only element, which have this css class. 
How can I select only the elements bordered with green and not the elements that are bordered in red?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

The ***:not***(...) selector is what you're looking for:

CSS:

```
<style>
    tr:not(tr>th) span.requestStatus { }
</style>
```

jQuery:

```
var selected_objects = $("tr:not(tr>th) span.requestStatus");
```

If you provide more details, as to what you're trying to actually "do" with each element, it would be easier to give additional instructions.

Comment: A tr is not a th, so your use of the :not() selector here is meaningless. (Also, the extended :not() syntax is [not supported in CSS in most browsers](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35993727/not-selector-not-behaving-the-same-between-safari-and-chrome-firefox).)

Comment: tr:not(tr>th) span.requestStatus { }   didn't work. I used instead the fact, that the td span.requeststatus is allways into a <tr .listRowOdd>. So this worked fine tr.listRowOdd span.requestStatus{   }

Answer (score 0):

**Try this :**

**1) Only Span element has class** `requestStatus` :

```
td span.requestStatus{
    *Css Code;*
}
```

**2) all Elements with class** `requestStatus` Except **img element**

```
td .requestStatus:not(img){
    *Css Code;*
}
```