# Select all elements between 2 headers (with variable ids)

Tags: css, css-selectors

I need to select all elements after one header and before another, then nothing after.

Ie, i need to select 1-5, but then not "no" in this example:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="mystyle.css"></link>
</head>
<body>
    <h4 id="this-is-bodger">0</h4>
    <p>1</p>
    <p>2</p>
    <p>3</p>
    <p>4</p>
    <p>5</p>
    <h3 id="that-is-the-badger">6</h3>
    <p>no</p>
</body>
</html>
```

I've tried this in CSS, but it highlights the "no":

```css
[id^=this-is] ~ p:not([id^=that-is]){
    color: red
}
```

How can I do this?

I thought [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42575173/how-to-select-all-elements-between-two-elements) would work, but it highlights no.

Note:

- the latter part of the ids changes after `this-is-` and `that-is-`
- i need to do this in one statement
- "no" must not be included

Comment: hi, perhaps add a second rule to undo the first rule for the remaining siblings `[id^=that-is] ~`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it like below. Select all the `p` after the first ID that are **not** after the second ID

```css
[id^=this-is] ~ p:not([id^=that-is] ~ *) {
  color: red
}
```

```html
<div>
  <h4 id="this-is-bodger">0</h4>
  <p>1</p>
  <p>2</p>
  <p>3</p>
  <p>4</p>
  <p>5</p>
  <h3 id="that-is-the-badger">6</h3>
  <p>no</p>
</div>
```