# Querying Html Hierarchy using advanced logic

Tags: html, css-selectors, selectors-api

Given html:

```
<div data-root="A">
 <div>Ignored</div>
 <div data-child="B">
  <div data-child="C" data-root="E">
    <div data-child="F"></div>
    <div data-child="G">
     <div data-root="Q">
      <div data-child="K"></div>
     </div>
    </div>
  </div>
 </div>
</div>
```

For any given element (root) I want to query all child elements having `data-child` attribute populated and not owned by another element with `data-root` specified.

Sample outcomes:

- Data Root A: Data children: B, C
- Data Root E: Data children: F, G, Q
- Data Root Q: Data children: K

I solved it by calling `root.querySelectorAll("[data-child]")` and then checking each element individually by tracing it up to the parent while checking if any elements by the way have `data-root` specified. It works, but the code is a bit awkward for what it's doing. Ideally I'm looking for a codeless declarative solution, can anyone come up with it for my problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only selector-based solution available, in the form

```
root.querySelectorAll("[data-child]:not(:scope [data-root] *)")
```

makes use of Selectors level 4 features that are [not yet supported by all browsers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35993727/not-selector-not-behaving-the-same-between-safari-and-chrome-firefox/35993791#35993791) and so probably won't work for your needs. There is no such solution available in Selectors level 3.

Comment: fair enough. I'll give it a try. How do I test for the support of Level 4 in Js to create a fallback?

Comment: @Simple.Js: I missed your previous comment. You can test this by putting this selector in a try {} and the fallback in a catch {}. No idea when Chrome is planning to support it unfortunately.

Answer (score 0):

Another not so well supported way to this would be to use  Element method [closest](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/closest) with the relevant selector.