# CSS :not selector - exclude multiple classes from hover

Tags: css

I'm combining three classes on elements

```
base, base_green, base_blue
```

I'm using this to add hover effect only to `base` class (without `base_green`)

```
.base:not(.base_green):hover {
    background-color: #E2E2E2;
}
```

How can I achive that with two classes?
meaning that, if element has `base base_green` or `base base_blue`, do not add hover effect on it
eg. something like this (doesn't work ofc)

```
.base:not(.base_green):not(.base_blue):hover {
    background-color: #E2E2E2;
}
```

**EDIT:**
Thank you all for answers, my initial solution works fine
I had a typo in that concatenated sausage of `:not` selectors in my css file
*/facepalm*

I'll leave question as it is, maybe someone finds it useful

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can I have multiple :not() selectors?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5684160/can-i-have-multiple-not-selectors)

Comment: No idea if you have other elements with classes containing the phrase "base_" that require this hover state applied, but if not, you could try `.base:not([class*="base_"]):hover` - otherwise, it may be easier to add a class, if possible, to elements that should not have this state applied and use that as a selector instead.

Comment: It's working for me, at least in Chrome: https://jsfiddle.net/7assquqp/

Answer (score 22, accepted):

This:

```
.base:not(.base_green):not(.base_blue):hover {
    background-color: #E2E2E2;
}
```

works perfectly fine if thrown in a [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/w2vtgxgh/1/)

Tested with the following HTML:

```
<div class="base base_green">GREEN</div>
<div class="base base_blue">BLUE</div>
<div class="base base_green base_blue">GREEN & BLUE</div>
<div class="base">BASE</div>
```

Comment: strange...it doesn't work on my side...I'll test it more

Comment: it works...I had a typo in css file :/ ...thanx for clearing that up

Comment: Ah, the good old typo ^^ they can be nasty, glad to have helped! good luck with the project @WolfWar

Comment: i was looking for less and found more :)

Comment: Perfect. Thanks very much.