# The use of CSS `*` with `:not()` within `@media print` still shows everything. What is the reason?

Tags: javascript, css

Trying to select what will be printed on `window.print()`.

Added the outmost element, so it contains childs elements (what explains the reason of using `.printable` **and** `.printable *`), class with `printable`, and added the style:

```
@media print{
    *:not(.printable *, .printable){
        display: none !important;
    }
}
```

The `window.print()`, when called, still shows everything.

[Example](https://codepen.io/gilkan/pen/yGQWPr)

**EDIT 1**

Tried to add `notPrintable` to all `:not(.printable, .printable *, .notPrintable)` with jQuery and refer `notPrintable` on `@media print`.

**Code:**

jQuery:

```
$(":not(.printable, .printable *, .notPrintable)").addClass("notPrintable");
```

CSS:

```
@media print{
    .notPrintable{
        display: none !important;
    }
}
```

Now nothing shows.

[Example 2](https://codepen.io/gilkan/pen/jXQojj)

**EDIT 2**

Putting the solution example here if anyone needs it (available only after having an answer marked as **accepted**):

[Example Final](https://codepen.io/gilkan/pen/roQEMW)

Comment: According to [this related Q/A](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/355313/how-do-i-hide-an-element-when-printing-a-web-page), you may want two separate style sheets where one sheet contains the CSS for the printed version of the page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$("body *:not(.printable, .printable *, .notPrintable)").addClass("notPrintable");
```

and

```
@media print{
  .notPrintable {
    display: none !important;
    }
}
```

did the trick.

The "selector" tip was given by @westdabestdb

Answer (score 1):

You can hide all elements and override the specific class in print media query.

```
@media print{
  body *:not(.printable) {
    display: none;
  }
}
```

Comment: Actually, I could **IF** all elements had block as display default. Tables need `display: table;`, for example. Already tried that. Thanks for trying.

Comment: Well, actually you are right. Let me think of something else.

Comment: What if you use 2 different stylesheets? 
`<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/screen.css" media="all">`
`<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/print.css" media="print">`

Comment: But the issue here is about the `:not()` selector, actually. Sooo... just tried to use the `:not()` within jQuery and add `not-printable` on all classes that aren't `printable`. <https://codepen.io/gilkan/pen/jXQojj> Now shows nothing...

Comment: @GilkanSolizaris I edited the answer. I feel like it works now.

Comment: Almost did the trick, if wasn't the child elements (I'll edit the question to alert about this). But good job.

Comment: Tried to change your selector to `body *:not(.printable, .printable *)` to solve the issue, but no success. That approach makes show everything.

Comment: Try `body *:not(.printable):not(.printable *)` (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5684160/can-the-not-pseudo-class-have-multiple-arguments).

Comment: @Vulcan tried that as well and didn't work. This `:not():not()` syntax is the same as "`not a AND not b`", so it's the same as "`not a,b`". Had to use the approach of my second example (trying to use jQuery) with @westdabestdb selector `body *:not(.printable)`. The final answer is in the Example Final link at the question.