# CSS: using negation on * all elements

Tags: css, css-selectors, negation

I want to select all `<img>` elements that are inside an `<article>` and not inside a `<figure>`

Following these 2:
[How to create a css rule for all elements except one class?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2489674/how-to-create-a-css-rule-for-all-elements-except-one-class)

https://www.w3.org/TR/css3-selectors/#negation

All `<img>` are wrapped in `<a>` or `<p>`. It seems it could be done with negation. My rule right now looks like this:

```
article *:not(figure) img { border: 2px solid red; }
```

Any tips tricks on why this is not working?

Comment: Can you post HTML necessary to reproduce the issue ?

Comment: Why not just specify different rules for `article img` vs. `figure img`? https://jsfiddle.net/ds33989g/

Comment: @alex thought about that, would prefer a slightly smarter way

Comment: I think @alex's way is the smartest one...

Comment: Selecting all `*` is not the smartest way. Those selectors are the slowest ones...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's working, but you're telling the browser that `img` elements do have to be wrapped in *something*. So `img` tags directly inside the `article` tag will not work, but anything nested e.g. in a `div` will:

```css
article *:not(figure) img { 
  border: 2px solid red; 
}
```

```html
<article>
  <img src="//placehold.it/50">
  <figure class="x">
    <img src="//placehold.it/50">
  </figure>
  <div>
    <img src="//placehold.it/50">
  </div>
</article>
```

What you probably need:

```css
article *:not(figure) img,
article > img{ 
  border: 2px solid red; 
}
```

```html
<article>
  <img src="//placehold.it/50">
  <figure class="x">
    <img src="//placehold.it/50">
  </figure>
  <div>
    <img src="//placehold.it/50">
  </div>
</article>
```

Please, do consider the advice from the comments, and see if your situation doesn't allow for an alternative solution that does not use the `*` universal and `:not` selector. E.g. this may be a lot simpler:

```css
article img {
  border: 2px solid red; 
}

article figure img { 
  border: none; 
}
```

```html
<article>
  <img src="//placehold.it/50">
  <figure class="x">
    <img src="//placehold.it/50">
  </figure>
  <div>
    <img src="//placehold.it/50">
  </div>
</article>
```

But whether that's usable for you depends on the entire context.

Comment: The universal selector is stupidly fast - it's a guaranteed match, and probably ignored by the browser in this context anyway. It's the :not() that's "slow" because it's one additional instruction to the browser, and it's only "slow" in that it's not optimized for a critical path unlike tagnames, ids and classes. Utilizing the cascade here is simply a no-brainer - you don't really need to come up with a reason for it.

Comment: @BoltClock Thanks for your feedback. It makes intuitive sense + I'll take your word for it. At any rate, I don't presume to know much about relative performance of selectors anyways. I've rewritten my answer slightly, weakened/removed claims about speed of selectors. As far as I can tell, even without details on perf, the post should be able to help OP.