# How to add css for element using not selector

Tags: html, css, sass

I'm using sass in my project to apply css styling, here i have div items where all `div`'s have same classes except few `div`s,

example: html

```
<div class="wrapper-col"><p>jakajsf</p></div>
<div class="wrapper-col"><p>jakajsf</p></div>
<div class="wrapper-col"><p>jakajsf</p></div>
<div class="wrapper-col"><p>jakajsf</p></div>
<div class="wrapper-col not-wrap"><p>jakajsf</p></div>
<div class="wrapper-col"><p>jakajsf</p></div>
<div class="wrapper-col"><p>jakajsf</p></div>
<div class="wrapper-col"><p>jakajsf</p></div>
<div class="wrapper-col"><p>jakajsf</p></div>
<div class="wrapper-col not-wrap"><p>jakajsf</p></div>
<div class="wrapper-col"><p>jakajsf</p></div>
```

above html has multiple divs with class name `wrapper-col`,but few div has also class not-wrap, i have scss here in which i want to apply styles having class name `wrapper-col` but not `not-wrap` class without modifying `HTML`

here is what i have tried, but its not working for me.

SCSS:

```
.wrapper-col{
    &:not(.not-wrap){
        p{
            /* styles here*/
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to create a css rule for all elements except one class?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2489674/how-to-create-a-css-rule-for-all-elements-except-one-class)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The example you pass works fine!

Add a border as an example and you will see it: https://jsfiddle.net/o7hjv1ts/1/

```
.wrapper-col{
    &:not(.not-wrap){
        p{
            border: 1px solid red;
        }
    }
}
```